# Entity model generate database from model error: database does not exist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I created my data model using Entity Framework, when I try to generate the database from the model, it generates the script but when I execute it I have the following error:

> *Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Database 'MyOp' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.*

I don't know where is the error, I don't think that is a problem of permissions.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to execute only the part of the script responsible for database creation and check that the database was really created.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it, sorry to ask such a question.
The problem was that my database was not created in my server, so I created it that way:
In SQL connecxion in visual studio, right click and add new database,
in the dialog box of the server name type ".\SQLEXPRESS" (without quotes).
Type the name of your db in the database name.
Now when executing your script, choose your database name instead of "master" in the dropdown list next the the excexution button.

WARNING: when changing laptop I did'nt find my created database, so you have to copy/paste it in the appdata folder in your application, to copy your database, you will find it in this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Answer (score 0):

you must click disconnect button and then connect button .vs2012 select sqlExpress by defult when you want connect again to your server you must select server name correctly.